# Why python's subprocess returns unexpected value?

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe

I wrote following program for an example --

```
from subprocess import *
import shlex


def pipe(command):
    proc = Popen(shlex.split(command), stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    out, err = proc.communicate()
    print "output:", out       # blank
    print "errors:", err       # expected output
    #return str(err)           # returns expected output
    return str(out)            # returns blanked output


out = pipe('python --version')
print 'pipe returned ----- %s' % out
```

Actually, **err** holds the expected value instead of **out**.

1. What is wrong with this code?
2. Is ***subprocess*** module is only used to handle basic OS's commands?

Comment: could you try another command? like `dir` on windows or `ls` on unix based systems? you may just gotten unlucky and python prints version info the stderr

Comment: What does "basic OS's commands" mean? You can run any process as a subprocess.

Comment: It is Ubuntu 18.04 @tripleee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main error is the unfounded assumption that version information will be displayed on standard output. This is poorly standardized, but Python - and many other Unix tools - sends this output to standard error.

Somewhat less crucially, you should probably be using `subprocess.run()` instead of raw `Popen()`; and not `import *`.

```
from subprocess import run, PIPE

out = run(['python', '--version'],
    stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, universal_newlines=True,
    check=True).stderr
```

If you like `shlex` you can use that to split the command into a list of two strings, though it seems rather superfluous in this case.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/51950538/87418 for (a lot) more details.

Comment: As the duplicate reveals, newer versions of Python actually print version information to stdout, since 3.4.

Comment: It's basically the same means I need to choose `stderr` no matter whether the process is initiated with `run` or `Popen()`. Actually, it goes back to --- ***Python - and many other Unix tools - sends this output to standard error***. Anyway, thanks for your great answer that provided in the comment section.